# AJAX url data send with friendly url's in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, friendly-url

I'm working in a page of Wordpress that reload the post showed in one DIV. The reload comes from the click in any post of the list under this DIV.

All is working fine but the problem is that i want to mantain friendly url's of Wordpress, and AJAX needs to send data in an url.

In frontend:

```
<div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" onClick="inlove_ajax(this.id); return false">
```

In AJAX file:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","wp-content/themes/37504/ajax_photo_reload.php?q="+str,true);
```

In PHP (ajax_photo_reload.php):

```
          require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php"); 
          $q=$_GET["q"]; 
          query_posts('p='.$q); 
          while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

I was thinking and trying different solutions:

- Add an exception in .htacces for these file
- Some way to send data with friendly urls

Comment: For you information there is already http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ site for wordpress Questions.

Answer (score 0):

For an AJAX request, there's no need to mantain friendly URLs, since they are not visible to the user (nor are they to search engines). You should use a format that is easy to parse, just as normal GET parameters are.

Comment: AJAX is only working in 3 pages of 76. Friendly url's are needed

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post, let me please advice you two things:

- Wordpress made use of AJAX easier using the built-in AJAX. It has many benefits, and this post is a useful example for you in my consideration: [Dynamically changing navigation links (next and previous) in Wordpress via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175020/dynamically-changing-navigation-links-next-and-previous-in-wordpress-via-ajax).
- Avoid using Onclick inside your HTML markup (read more about unobtrusive JS).

I am here to provide with support.
Good luck

Comment: Good info, thanks! I use these info to rewrite my code, and it works, but happens exactly the same, without friendly urs works, with firnedly works can't pass data in url and doesn't work

Comment: i dont understand you well; but if you use my advice, you will gain in terms of security: it is anyway a major issue. feedback to me when you resolve the friendly url problem so that i learn from your experience

Comment: I solved. Writing in this line the right path it rules alone: url: 'wp-content/themes/twentyten/pages/next-previous.php?p='+id,