# Ajax load more button in Recent posts widget wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I create Recent posts Wordpress widget and i trying to create load more button for it to get more Recent posts links by ajax, like twitter ,is there any tutorial for how to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at source of [infinite scroll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/) plugin,it's do what exactly you need,and also to develop something like that ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315024/865477) can help you.

Comment: is this things works with widget too? 
because widget not have links like page/2/ and page/3/